# Encrypting data using Win32/MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, encryption, mfc, cryptography

I want to encrypt the data I am sending to the server using a public key. I searched on the internet for doing this using Win32 or MFC but got confused with different APIs used (like CryptExportKey, CryptImportKey, CryptGenKey etc). Can anybody point me to some resource where I can learn how to do this?

Comment: A lot here will depend on what your server wants/uses (or are you developing both the client and the server?)

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Yes, I am developing both server and client.

Comment: Why not use something like RSA? It is fairly easy to implement RSA in straight out C code. There are probably a few RSA implementations already out there in the wild.

Comment: If you're not trying to match something that's built in, I'd personally avoid the Win32 functions -- they can certainly do the job, but as you've already observed, they're clumsy to work with, and rather poorly documented, at least in terms of how to fit them together to accomplish anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options the newer [CNG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) api or the older [CryptoAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_security_cryptoapi_gly). These are the two native code interfaces for cryptography on windows. There is not any MFC specific one. CNG may not be 32bit, but CryptoAPI is although you may need to define

```
_WIN32_WINNT
```

to enable that support.

Comment: CNG is applicable in both 32 bit and 64 bit applications.

Comment: and you need more than _WIN32_WINNT to use CNG. Header and lib.

Comment: And CNG is only available on Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, or newer. So, if you need to support older operating systems you'd need to use a different implementation.